# How to create new column that can combine adjacent but broken up "on" values into groups using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column of 1s (corresponding to an "ON" signal) and 0s (corresponding to an "off" signal).

My data has some noise in it, such that the first "ON" signal has some 0s in the middle which makes it appear broken up. The same happens with the other "ON" signals. This makes it hard to count how many "ON" signals are in my data in total. It looks like there are more than there are!

Is there a way for me to group these, filling in the gaps? Ideally i would like to make a new column that indicates the current number of "ON" signals up to that time.
[image]

I have tried a rolling mean and threshold type approach...any help would be appreciated.

This gives me the locations when it changes from an "ON" to an "OFF", letting me look up the time index when it occurs:

```
df.loc[:,'Change'] = np.abs(df['ONOFF_Signal'].diff())
On_off_timestamps = df.query("Change == 1")['Time'].values

##Sample_data for two "ON" groupings. 
df['Change'] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

#Output wanted: 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

##So that I can generate a count column "mask" up to each row of how many "ON" values have occurred: 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sensibly the same approach as yours, but using a double [`rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html) (forward/backward) and then getting the [`minimum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) of the two:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Change': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

import numpy as np
df['rolled'] = np.minimum(df['Change'].rolling(3, min_periods=0).max(),
                          df.loc[::-1, 'Change'].rolling(3, min_periods=0).max())
```

Visual example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right, after a lot of messing about, this seems to work....i would love to hear if there is a better way of doing this. My approach is very messy!!

```
  #Set the gap length to detect
    gap_length = 40
        
    #Create a boolean mask to identify where signal changes occur
    mask = df['change'].ne(df['change'].shift()) | (df['change'].rolling(gap_length+1).sum() == 0)
        
    #Generate a grouping identifier for each contiguous sequence of "ON" signals
    group_id = mask.cumsum()
        
    #Use groupby and cumcount to generate a count of "ON" signals up to each row
    df['mask'] = df.groupby(group_id).cumcount() + 1
        
    #Replace the 0's with NaN values
    df['mask'][df['mask'] > 1] = 0
        
    #Apply rolling window - signal inverted, so *1+1 to flip it and center it 
    df['mask'] = (df['mask'].rolling(window=3, center=True).min()*-1)+1

    # pick out where the filled in mask changes
    df['on_number'] = d['mask'].diff()

    # Keep only the first "ON" signal
    df['on_number'][df['on_number'] < 0] = 0

    # Sum on signals to get a rolling count of true "ONs"
    df['on_number'] = df['on_number'].cumsum()
```